# Can Apache nifi be used as an application server?

Tags: webserver, apache-nifi, application-server, diagramming, flow-based-programming

I'm an application developer mainly develop and maintain enterprise application, like ERP, HCM system. After being in the field for many years, I started feeling that the way business system are developed is not quite right. After years of maintenance and enhancement by hundreds of developers, the system keeps getting bigger and bigger, more and more complex. At the end, it just impossible to do big changes in the system, because the logics are all tangled together like Italian noodles. Developers so afraid of causing severe customer issues.

Recently I find [Flow based programming paradigm](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/index.shtml) invented by [J. Paul Morrison](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/) and I find it really interesting. I approve very much the idea of doing application development by drawing diagram visually. As we all know to develop business system we start with drawing business flow diagram. Why can't business flow diagram just be the system itself??

Naturally, I tried to find FBP implementations, and nifi is the one that the FBP inventor recommends. I haven't dig very deep into nifi.

Just after watching some introduction videos and documentation, I find most of the time, the nifi experts always talking about using nifi for iot system, real time streaming these kind of stuff. It seems that nifi is not related to business systems.

Looking forward to someone to clarify my doubts. Is nifi suitable for building business transactional systems?

Answer (score 3):

Apache NiFi is definitely used for many "business logic" systems, especially taking on the role of handling extract/transform/load logic (ETL). While not strictly an ETL tool, NiFi can facilitate data routing and simple event processing in a number of scenarios. The ["Powered By NiFi" page](https://nifi.apache.org/powered-by-nifi.html) lists some public use cases of NiFi, and many are for "business systems" that do not relate to IoT.

Answer (score 2):

sorry I didn't see your question before - your comments are interesting.  I am surprised that you say that NiFi is the FBP software that I recommend - I do list it as a product that is closer to the "classical" FBP philosophy than what we call "FBP-like" or "FBP-inspired" systems, and I assume it is one of the few FBP products that are in the marketplace - unlike my work, which is all public domain.  The terms "FBP-like" and "FBP-inspired" are actually thanks to Joe Witt, the developer of NiFi.  I try to describe the difference between "classical" FBP and "FBP-like" in my article on https://jpaulm.github.io/fbp/noflo.html .  With all due respect to Joe, I find NiFi a bit over-complex, although his data packets are immutable, which has certain advantages.  For a complete suite that takes you from a diagram to actual running code, I would suggest you start with the FBP diagramming tool, https://github.com/jpaulm/drawfbp , generate a JavaFBP network, using https://github.com/jpaulm/javafbp , and run!  Both of these tools, as well as others on https://github.com/jpaulm/ , are open source.  My colleague, Bob Corrick, and I are working on a tutorial which you may find helpful: https://github.com/jpaulm/fbp-tutorial-filter-file .